# You toss a coin $n$ times; $m$ times you get heads. What is the probability that it is a fair coin?

Tags: probability

You toss a coin $n$ times; $m$ times you get heads. What is the probability that it is a fair coin?

*My solution*:

A fair coin will give us probability of $0.5$ of getting heads.

Assume:
$\;\;\;n=100$ tosses, $\;\;m=50$ heads,
$\;\;p=0.5$.

$$P(X=50)=\frac{100!}{(50!*50!)}*0.5^{50}*0.5^{50} = 0.079.$$

So there's a $7.9$% chance that the coin is fair.

Am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: $0.079 \neq 79\%$

Comment: Thanks I fixed it

Comment: There is literally no way to tell. It depends on the PDF of the random value $p,$ the probability of heads for a rand9m coin. For example, if all coins are fair, the probability that it is fair is $1.$ If half of them are fair and the other half have $p=m/n,$ then the probability is less than $1.$ If $p$ is uniform, you get another value.

Comment: You are confusing the probability of getting $m$ heads in $n$ tosses *given* a fair coin with the probability of having a fair coin *given* $m$ heads in $n$ tosses.  You don't have a probability distribution defined for fair and unfair coins, so nothing can be said about the probability of a fair coin regardless of the experimental outcome.

Comment: Your calculation only tells you that a fair coin has a probability of approximately 0.079 of showing _exactly_ 50 heads in 100 consecutive tosses.  That does not by itself provide any information on judging the "fairness" of the coin.  The probability would be exactly the same if 100 "fair" coins were tossed simultaneously and we wanted to find the probability of _exactly_ 50 heads showing.

Comment: Why is $m = 50$? Have you considered $m = 78$, $m = 92$ or even $m = 2$? Basically all values of $0 < m < n$. By **purposely** choosing $m = 50$ or $m = \frac{n}{2}$, so that you will obtain a higher chance of $p = 0.5$ in your answer, you are reducing the validity of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With known values of $n$ and $m$, you cannot derive a probability for $p$ to be an exact value, but you can derive a range so that $p$ is within this range (i.e. confidence interval CI) with a certain probability (i.e. confidence level CL).

For instance, when $n=100$ and $m=50$, $p$ will be within (0.4 ~ 0.6) with a probability of 95%.